# Can't access HDFS on Mesosphere DC/OS despite "healthy" status

Tags: amazon-web-services, hdfs, mesos, mesosphere, dcos

So I've deployed a Mesos cluster in AWS using the CloudFormation script / instructions found [here](https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.7/administration/installing/cloud/aws/) with the default cluster settings (5 private slaves, one public slave, single master, all m3.xlarge), and installed HDFS on the cluster with the `dcos` command: `dcos package install hdfs`.

The HDFS service is apparently up and healthy according to the DC/OS web UI and Marathon:
[image: Mesos UI showing running HDFS]

**(the problem)** At this point I should be able to SSH into my slave nodes and execute `hadoop fs` commands, but that returns the error `-bash: hadoop: command not found` (basically telling me there is no `hadoop` installed here).

There are no errors coming from the STDOUT and STDERR logging for the HDFS service, but for what its worth there is a recurring "offer decline" message appearing in the logs:

`Processing DECLINE call for offers: [ 5358a8d8-74b4-4f33-9418-b76578d6c82b-O8390 ] for framework 5358a8d8-74b4-4f33-9418-b76578d6c82b-0001 (hdfs) at scheduler-60fe6c75-9288-49bc-9180-f7a271c …`

I'm sure I'm missing something silly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out **a** solution to at least verifying HDFS is running on your Mesos DC/OS cluster after install.

1. SSH into your master with the `dcos` CLI: `dcos node ssh --master-proxy --leader`
2. Create a docker container with hadoop installed to query your HDFS: `docker run -ti cloudera/quickstart hadoop fs -ls hdfs://namenode-0.hdfs.mesos:9001/`

---

### Why this isn't a good solution & what to look out for:

1. [Previous documentation](https://github.com/mesosphere/hdfs#using-hdfs) all points to a default URL of `hdfs://hdfs/`, which instead will throw a `java.net.UnknownHostException`. I don't like pointing directly to a namenode.
2. [Other documentation](https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.7/usage/service-guides/spark/install/#scrollNav-5) suggests you can run `hdfs fs ...` commands when you SSH into your cluster - this does not work as documented.
3. The image I used just to test that you can access HDFS is > 4GB (better options?)
4. None of this is documented (or at least not clearly/completely, hence why I'm keeping this post updated). I had to dig through DC/OS slack chat to find an answer.
5. [The Mesosphere/HDFS repo](https://github.com/mesosphere/hdfs) is a completely different version than the HDFS that is installed via `dcos package install hdfs`. That repo is no longer maintained and the new version isn't open sourced yet (hence the lack of current documentation I guess).

---

I'm hoping there is an easier way to interface with HDFS that I'm still missing. Any better solutions would still be very helpful!